# How can I filter a list of items using jquery's .each()?

Tags: jquery

When using .each(), is there a way to filter the elements it examines?

Currently, this is what I have: given a list of elements, I only want to examine inputs.

> ```
> $.each (Items, function(i, item) {
>     if (item.is("input"))
>         (do something)
> });
> ```

Comment: I would advice to put filter in the selecter itself.

Comment: can you show your Item array or object on which you're doing `each`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, theres a method called [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) - just apply this to your `Items` to filter the set before iterating:

```
$.each (Items.filter('input'), function(i, item) {
    // do something
});
```

another way to write this would be to call `.each` directly on the set (the result is the same):

```
Items.filter('input').each(function(i, item) {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: This assumes `Items` is a jQuery object. `$.each` can work on any collection, so it may not work. (actually, there `item.is("input")`, so this probably isn't an issue)

Comment: I assumed `Items` is a jQuery collection because of `item.is("input")` used. in that case, it's just a personal choise of style how to write this loop (i'd prefer `Items.filter().each()`, too).

Comment: Personal choice yes, though I think that `Items.each()` is nicer than `$.each(Items...` because it's shorter and it's chainable. (I guess this note is more for the OP than for you, oezi.)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `if` statement is ok, or you could use `.filter` method.

```
Items.filter("input").each(function() {
 // do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For learning experiences, in regards to the code in your question, here's how you would go about it:

```
$.each(Items, function(i, item) {
    if($(this).is('input')) {
        // do something
    }
});​
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g6Jsr/